kvm libvirt: Port Forwarding via nft not working
I use KVM to virtualize a Guest-Linux-Mint on my Host-Debian12. The Guest is obviously configured well with NAT: I can ssh into the Guest from the Host, I can reach the Internet from the Guest.
But I can't get Port-Forwarding to work. I want to SSH into the Guest from any Remote Computer via IPv4 and Port 3022. The Host is accessible from a Remote via its public IPv4-Address.
The ip6-Tables in nft where configured by libvirt. I just added the rules in table ip nat
UPDATE
There are no IPv4-Rules generated by libvirt in my nft-rules. Maybe this is one Problem. But how do I configure libvirt to generate these rules? Or should I configure them manually? If so, what are the right rules?
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

nft list ruleset
table ip6 filter {
    chain LIBVIRT_INP {
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 3 bytes 208 jump LIBVIRT_INP
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_OUT {
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 42 bytes 2464 jump LIBVIRT_OUT
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWO {
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWX
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWI
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWO
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWI {
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWX {
    }
}
table ip6 nat {
    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
    }
}
table ip6 mangle {
    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type filter hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        counter packets 42 bytes 2464 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
    }
}
table ip nat {
    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        ip daddr 192.168.122.1 masquerade
    }

    chain prerouting {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
        tcp dport 3022 dnat to 192.168.122.167:22
    }
}

UPDATE 2
So I ditched all nft-Rules on my host and used these standard-filter-rules, added by my nat-rules:
nft list ruleset
table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
    }
}
table ip nat {
    chain prerouting {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
        tcp dport 3022 dnat to 192.168.122.167:22
    }

    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 masquerade
    }
}

I don't understand, why kvm adds the ip6-rules, shown in my initial post, but the GUEST reaches the internet even with this ruleset. So I'm fine with this (I do not need IPv6).
But I still can't figure out, how to solve my problem: From the HOST I can reach port 22 of the GUEST and ssh into the machine by ssh user@192.168.122.167, but I cannot ssh -p 3022 user@203.190.3.5 (which is the IP-Address of the HOST).
What am I missing?

what research did you already? have you tried chatgpt? because you don't mention any references that you tried an what commands has been used so far to solve it?

@djdomi I just updated my question with what I have tried so far.

Libvirt normally sets up netfilter rules that block external connections to your virtual machines. For example, I have a libvirt network k3sint using the 172.17.17.0/24 address range. Libvirt generated the following rules in the FORWARD chain:
table ip filter {
  chain FORWARD {
    type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
    counter jump LIBVIRT_FWX
    counter jump LIBVIRT_FWI
    counter jump LIBVIRT_FWO
  }

  chain LIBVIRT_FWI {
    oifname "k3sint" ip daddr 172.17.17.0/24 ct state related,established counter accept
    oifname "k3sint" counter reject
  }
}

Those rules in the LIBVIRT_FWI chain (FWI == "forward input") cause any forwarded connection to that address range to get rejected. If I want this to work:
table inet mynat {
  chain mynat_PREROUTING {
    type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat + 10; policy accept;
    counter tcp dport 3022 dnat ip to 172.17.17.174:22
  }
}

Then I also need to permit that forwarded connection. Due to the way netfilter works, we need to place the accept rule in the filter FORWARD chain somewhere before the reject rule shown above. We can prepend the rule to the LIBVIRT_FWI chain by running:
nft insert rule ip filter LIBVIRT_FWI \
  counter oifname "k3sint" ip daddr 172.17.17.174 \
  tcp dport 22 accept

Now I'm able to connect to myhost:3022 and have that connection redirected to the virtual machine at 172.17.17.174.

Thanks, but I do not have any table ip rules, only table ip6. Maybe there is something of IPv4 missing in my config.
